# Prevent Session.Timeout Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, timeout, code-behind

How to prevent `Session.Timeout` extension on certain event from codebehind?

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer7" runat="server" Interval="540000" ontick="Timer7_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
```

---

```
protected void Timer7_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showModalPopupServerOperatorButton_Click(null, null);
            Timer7.Enabled = false;
}
```

Initial calculations was that 1 minute before the session ends, i'll inform the user something with the `ModalPopup`. The problem is that when this `Timer7_Tick` event triggers, the `Session.Timeout` renew and the session ends 10 minutes later (if user still don't send any request from his browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side execution will extend session timeout. If you just want to popup a dialog, try using `JavaScript` without any postbacks.

[`15+ jQuery Popup Modal Dialog Plugins and Tutorials.`](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/)

An alternative of using `Timer control`, use this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    setTimeout(function () {    
        alert("Event");    
    }, 540000);    
</script>
```

Comment: İ think, i should prefer to use JQuery in my project.. Thanks!